# Error when trying to reach own remote node

Tags: monerod, daemon

I've created a node on a VPS server. I run the node this way:

```
monerod --rpc-bind-ip <IP_SERVER> --rpc-bind-port 18089 --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --detach --data-dir=/mnt/volume1
```

But when I try to get the status I get this message:

```
monerod --rpc-bind-ip <IP_SERVER> --rpc-bind-port 18089 --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --detach --data-dir=/mnt/volume1 status

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: <IP_SERVER>:18089
Height: 1478406/1478406 (100.0%) on mainnet, mining info unavailable, net hash 561.65 MH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+28(in) connections, uptime 4d 0h 37m 23s
```

What does this mean? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

status uses a few RPC to the daemon, and one of them (asking for mining status) is restricted. Calling it errors out since you used --restricted-rpc, and you see it tells you "mining info unavailable".

If you want to get access to the server's mining info, remove --restricted-rpc (but then anyone else can get that info from your server). In that case you probably want to connect through a ssh tunnel, or set a password.

Comment: I don't want to mine. I just want to check if monero is running and the blockchain is sync correctly. Also, if someone discovers <IP_SERVER> can they stole my XMR?

Comment: No, unless your system is vulnerable somehow and also running a monero wallet (or having the keys/seed stored there). The monerod daemon does not have access to your private keys.